# simple regex - between double quotations replace space with underscore and make all letters lowercase

Tags: regex, vim

Could you help me with a regex to change lines like

```
<string name="Final time">Final time</string>
<string name="After extra time">After extra time</string>
```

to lines

```
<string name="final_time">Final time</string>
<string name="after_extra_time">After extra time</string>
```

So between double quotations replace space with underscore and make all letters lowercase.

I will use this regex with search/replace in VIM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generic approach:

```
:%s/\(<string name="\)\(\u\)\([^" ]\+\) \([^" ]\+\)/\1\l\2\e\3_\4/
```

This replaces every string @name that

- starts with an upper case character (`\u`) and
- consists of two space-separated words (`\([^" ]\+\) \([^" ]\+\)`) and
- replaces it with the corresponding lower-case character (`\l\2\e`).
- It also replaces the space with an underscore.

---

To make everything in @name lower-case, this could be simplified:

```
:%s/\(<string name="\)\([^" ]\+\) \([^" ]\+\)/\1\l\2_\3_\e/
```

---

To get rid of multiple spaces, do two steps. First, make the attribute value lower-case:

```
:%s/\(<string name="\)\([^"]\+\)/\1\l\2\e/
```

then, replace every space in the attribute value with an underscore

```
:%s/\(<string name="[^"]*\)\@<= /_/g
```

Note that the `\@<=` is vim's way of expressing a positive look-behind assertion.

Comment: Almost works, but from line <string name="Top Scorers">Top Scorers</string> it made <string name="t_op">Top Scorers</string>

Comment: It means that this regex replaced <string name="Top Scorers">Top Scorers</string> with <string name="t_op">Top Scorers</string> instead of <string name="top_scorers">Top Scorers</string>

Comment: @Tomasz If you have multiple words (not just two), you need a two-step approach: First replace the upper-case letters, then the spaces.

Comment: Works, thank you. It blows my mind. Could you make it to work in even more generic case. So not only for two space separated words, but for any number of words. Also to replace any upper case letter to lower case letter.

Comment: @Tomasz I cannot make it work with any number of spaces in one step, sorry. However, to make everything lower-case, just move the `\l` to the start of the replacement expression and the `\e` to the end. Everything between `\l` and `\e` is converted to lower-case. (`\l\2\3_\4\e`)

Comment: I think that my answer is wrong because the question changed while I was writing the answer.  Of course, this can happen on Stackoverflow sometimes, can't it?  In light of your answer, though, I don't think that mine is really necessary any longer, so let me just remove mine and upvote yours.  That's simplest.

Comment: @thb Don't. Yours contains good advice (especially the macro explanation, but also the hint to keep simple things simple) that might very well be valuable to the next guy that comes along.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I also see that it was easier to have two regexs, one for uppercase to lowercase, second for space to underscore. It is a tip for me for the future.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is outdated and does not fully answer the question as presently asked.  However, it is retained here rather than deleted on the advice of another answerer.)

If you want a regex that cannot be fooled, why, that will take some work.  While using Vim, though, one usually takes a more relaxed attitude.  Does this not serve?

```
:s/"final time"/"final_time"/g
```

You can omit the trailing `g` if you want replacement to occur only once.  On the other hand, you can make it

```
:s/"\cfinal time"/"final_time"/g
```

to make the pattern-match case-insensitive (though, really to do this right, see @Tomalak's answer).

However, while using Vim, there may be an easier way, as follows.

1. Press `qq` to start recording Macro `q` (or `qa` to start recording Macro `a`, etc., as you prefer; if unsure, `qq` is quickest to type and as good as any other).
2. Type the search command `/"\cfinal time"` and press enter.
3. Press `f<Space>` or `6l` to move the cursor over to the space.
4. Press `r_` to replace the space with an underscore.
5. Press `q` to finish recording the macro.

Then, if you like, you can immediately press `@q` to make Vim repeat the same operations automatically.  This is quick, and useful, if you have several strings `"final time"` scattered throughout your file that all want the same edit.  Even better, the *third* and subsequent time you want Vim to do the same operations, you can just press `@@` to repeat the last `@` operation.  This is extra quick.

(Thanks to @Tomalak for adding that `/"\cfinal time"` modifies the search to be case-insensitive.  I had not known that.)

Comment: @Tomalak:  I admit that `\c` is unfamiliar to me.  On the other hand, it looks as though the OP has updated the question after I started to answer, so I'll look at it again, and investigate `\c`.  Thanks.

Comment: `\c` is case-insensitive regex. Your's wouldn't match.

Comment: @thb Thank you, but I meant much more generic case than just a string 'final time'. It is about any string, with any number of words.